# SSIS - Read select from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I have query in table.
For Example:

```
SELECT 1 AS pocet_zaznamu " + @[$Package::db]
+ ".ads.ea_meta_auta_sleva
```

I read data into project.
Now I have:

```
SELECT 1 AS pocet_zaznamu \" + @[$Package::db] + \".ads.ea_meta_auta_sleva
```

How I remove back slash from string?

Comment: Okay, please also provide which component are you using.

Comment: In Data Flow Task I read query from table. Result I save through RecordSet into variable resultset. Type is Object. Over  Foreach Loop Object (ADO numerator) I save data info variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to write an expression in the OLEDB Source SQL Command, but you are writing it in the wrong place.

You can simply add a variable of type string example `@[User::strQuery]`, and change its `EvaluateAsExpression` property to `True`, click on  the expression field and write the following expression:

```
"SELECT 1 AS pocet_zaznamu " + @[$Package::db] + ".ads.ea_meta_auta_sleva"
```

Now go to the OLE DB Source, and change the Data Access mode to `SQL Command from variable` and select `@[User::strQuery]`